# Making a POST REST API call in Power Bi Query Functions to generate a token, and used that JWT based token to make another GET API Call

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have requirement to make a POST REST API call using Power Bi Query Functions to get the JWT access token. Then use the same token obtained make a GET API call to obtain data that has to be displayed in a Power Bi Dashboard.

Now the issue is, I am not able to get the first part right, to get the access token. I need to be pass the client id, client secret and resource uri as a body of the POST API to get the token.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can your describe the request specification required to get the access token? I don't think we can answer without knowing that, because the authentication method depends on the specific system. If you have been able to do that in any other language, please share that.

Comment: yes, to get the access token, it is supposed to be a POST call and in the body of the POST call it should have the Client ID, Client Secret, Resource URI and the GRANT Type with the specific set of values.
The response of the call should contain the JWT access token, like this:
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1548",
    "not_before": "157448",
    "resource": "resource-uri",
    "access_token": "token"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it ultimately worked for me:

```
let

    GetJson = Web.Contents("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/oauth2/token",
        [
            Headers = [# "Accept" = "application/json",
                # "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
            ],
            Content = Text.ToBinary("client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx&client_secret=xx***xx:/xxx?***&resource=api://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials")
        ]
    ),
    FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
    # "Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(FormatAsJson),
    # "Expanded Value" = Table.Last(# "Converted to Table"),
    access_token = List.Last(Record.FieldValues(# "Expanded Value")),
    source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://my-web-api.azurewebsites.net/api/get_my_data?Num=100", [Headers = [ContentType = "application/json"]])),
    Result = Json.Document(source)
    in
    # "Result"
```

Please update the required credentials/secrets/id or any relevant field to get this working. But I would request Microsoft or any Microsoft affiliated Power Bi Developer to create a more comprehensive article or document on these topics.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample to get the token:

```
let
   url = "XXXXXXXXXXXX/api/",
   body =
    "{""client_id"":""XXX"",""client_secret"":""XXX"",""resource_uri"":""XXXXXX""}",
   Source  = 
   Json.Document(
       Web.Contents(
           url,
           [ 
               Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"],
               Content=Text.ToBinary(body)
           ]
       )
   )
in
   Source
```

After getting the token with the above query, you can use it in another query to make the 2nd call and get the actual data.

Comment: I am getting a data source error, with this implementation:
DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from "url"
Bad Request
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Web

Comment: Please edit your question, and post the query you used and the full error text as well. @AdityaBhattacharya